# Как удалить скобки и содержимое правильно через replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, replace

Есть строка

```
<div>          
<ins data-revive-zoneid="98"></ins></div--!>
</div>
```

И мне нужно удалить только </div--!>
Но регулярным выражением

```
preg_replace('/.*?<.*--!>.*?/', '', $str)
```

Удаляет полностью вся строка

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="98"></ins></div--!>
```

Как удалить только </div--!>  ?

Comment: Укажите в метках вопроса язык программирования, который используете.

Comment: Судя по "беременному" именованию функций работы с регулярками (`preg_replace`), языком программирования тут является PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/<\/.\w*--!>/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы.